# How to remove language switching option from lockscreen on macos

Tags: keyboard, lockscreen

I have a bunch of not so fun colleagues at my work that get fun about changing my keyboard language on the lockscreen, using the topbar menu.
I've looked the internet but I haven't found any option to remove this.

Can you help me about that ?

Comment: Report them to management/HR - you're there to work, not play.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlaa57f797/mac